# ACF for WordPress is not saving location data! Can't see the fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Something has occurred, where ACF is not saving the location settings - that defines where the fields are shown in the admin.

It used to work, but now it is broken for some reason.

[image]

I'm trying to save it as page, but it's not saving!

I'm still able to add fields to ACF...so, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Where is this value stored in the DB? I could perhaps edit it manually as a short-term fix.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Disable all other plugins and swap the theme to check for conflicts.

Comment: @brasofilo I think I discovered a bug in ACF. I will investigate further and update this thread. Thanks though!

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?